unable to access GPS data from /ttyAMA0 port
I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B running Ubuntu 20.04 server mode, connected to a Neo-7M GPS module (link to product). The connections are as follows:
5V (GPS) to 5V (Raspberry Pi)
GND to GND
TX (GPS) to RX (Raspberry Pi, ttyAMA0)
To set up the GPS, I made the necessary changes to the configuration files, such as enabling the UART in:
/boot/config.txt
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
enable_uart=1

/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
elevator=deadline net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc quiet splash cfg80211.ieee80211_regdom=IN

/boot/firmware/config.txt
# Please DO NOT modify this file; if you need to modify the boot config, the
# "usercfg.txt" file is the place to include user changes. Please refer to
# the README file for a description of the various configuration files on
# the boot partition.

# The unusual ordering below is deliberate; older firmwares (in particular the
# version initially shipped with bionic) don't understand the conditional
# [sections] below and simply ignore them. The Pi4 doesn't boot at all with
# firmwares this old so it's safe to place at the top. Of the Pi2 and Pi3, the
# Pi3 uboot happens to work happily on the Pi2, so it needs to go at the bottom
# to support old firmwares.

[pi4]
kernel=uboot_rpi_4.bin

[pi2]
kernel=uboot_rpi_2.bin

[pi3]
kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin

[pi0]
kernel=uboot_rpi_3.bin

[all]
device_tree_address=0x03000000

[pi4]
max_framebuffers=2
arm_boost=1

[all]
# Enable the audio output, I2C and SPI interfaces on the GPIO header. As these
# parameters related to the base device-tree they must appear *before* any
# other dtoverlay= specification
dtparam=audio=on

dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Comment out the following line if the edges of the desktop appear outside
# the edges of your display
disable_overscan=1

# If you have issues with audio, you may try uncommenting the following line
# which forces the HDMI output into HDMI mode instead of DVI (which doesn't 
# support audio output)
#hdmi_drive=2

# Config settings specific to arm64
arm_64bit=1
dtoverlay=dwc2

[cm4]
# Enable the USB2 outputs on the IO board (assuming your CM4 is plugged into
# such a board)
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

[all]

# The following settings are "defaults" expected to be overridden by the
# included configuration. The only reason they are included is, again, to
# support old firmwares which don't understand the "include" command.

enable_uart=1
cmdline=cmdline.txt

include syscfg.txt
include usercfg.txt

dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt

Issue:
i wrote a python script which just reads the data being recieved on this port and print it on the terminal
import serial

# Set up the serial connection
serial_port = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
baud_rate = 9600  # GPS modules typically use 9600 baud

try:
    # Initialize the serial connection
    ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baud_rate, timeout=1)
    print(f"Listening on {serial_port} at {baud_rate} baud rate...")

    while True:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:  # Check if there is data available
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore').strip()
            print(line)  # Print the received line
except serial.SerialException as e:
    print(f"Error opening serial port {serial_port}: {e}")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nExiting...")
finally:
    if 'ser' in locals() and ser.is_open:
        ser.close()

I had provided completed access to the port
sudo chmod +777 /dev/ttyAMA0

Question:
How to actually access that port via python script for further processing?

Are you sure this RPi model can accept 5 volts on that RXD pin? A quick web search says "no, the max is 3.3V." If you applied a voltage higher than max rating, you may have permanently damaged the device.

Hey @Mike973
Thank you for pointing that out.
The GPS module I am using sends 3.3V only even when powered with 5V. I confirmed by checking the readings via a multimeter too.

I think your chmod command isn't actually providing access unless you are a member of a group that can access the port. What is the group membership for the ttyAMA0 port?
Are you a member of the dialout group? And is the serial login shell disabled? I suggest showing ls -al /dev/ttyAMA0
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/132147/how-can-i-prevent-raspbian-from-resetting-user-privileges-on-dev-tttys0

Thanks Gordon,
The actual problem was that the permissions were being reset by serial-getty, and even disabling it was not working as on every reboot it the services just start again. I finally masked it so that it get ignored properly using the command
sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service.
Now everything is working fine.

Glad you could get it working and good to show the resolution if someone else has the same issue!
